# Setting up SSH proxy for only some servers in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I followed the steps described in http://returnbooleantrue.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-github-through-draconian-proxies.html, but then connecting to the internal server fails:

```
Proxy could not open connnection to 192.168.1.***:  Forbidden
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Can I set up `config` file so that `ProxyCommand` is only used for ssh.github.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Put that directive in a separate `Host` stanza.

```
Host github-external
    HostName ssh.github.com
    ProxyCommand dosomethinghere
```

Then use `github-external` as the hostname.